# NoMethodError in Recipes#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm having a problem with creating categories.

Ruby on Rails gives this message when trying to to view the categories:

```
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :category %><br /> 
   <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, :prompt => true %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories ? @categories : [], :id, :name, :prompt => true %>
```

According to the `collection_select` method `@categories` should be an array of the objects,
the error is occur as it's get the value `@categories` as a `nil`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your new action method in your Recipes controller you need to populate @categories.

e.g/

```
def new
   @categories = Category.all
   # .. other code
end
```

Comment: Just a suggested tidy-up: `Category.all` will never return nil, making `|| []` unnecessary.